# Debunking an elementary proof of FLT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, fake-proofs

> José Cayolla: Fermat's Last Theorem admits an infinity of proving ways and two corollaries. [arXiv:1507.06989](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06989) [math.GM]

I don't usually devote so much time to "crackpot papers", but I have a friend who thinks there may be something to this one and has written up the complete proof a few different ways in order to make it as clear as possible to me, and so I feel the need to pinpoint exactly why this paper is wrong. Unfortunately neither the original author nor my friend is a native English speaker, and I don't want to let trivial errors get in the way of finding the real problems here.

To summarize the argument, we want to show that $x^n+y^n=z^n$ has no solutions for $x<y<z$ and $n\ge3$, and we view this as fixing $x,y,z$ and varying $n$. For small $n$ we have $z^n<x^n+y^n$ and for large $n$ this reverses to $z^n>x^n+y^n$, and there is at most one $n$ for which equality is attained (which would be a counterexample). Letting $n-1$ be the largest number satisfying $z^{n-1}<x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}$, FLT is equivalent to showing $z^n>x^n+y^n$.

(page 7:) The "infinity of proving ways" in the title refers to the interval $z^n\ge \zeta_n\ge x^n+y^n$ of possible witnesses $\zeta_n$ to this inequality. (Here I am a bit concerned: why not $z^n>\zeta_n\ge x^n+y^n$?) To find these $\zeta$ values we use another auxiliary $\lambda$ which satisfies the equation
$$\lambda z^{n-1}\geq x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}\implies z^n>x^n+y^n.\tag{19}$$
(The text before this equation seems to suggest $\lambda z^{n-1}\geq x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}\wedge z^n>x^n+y^n$ instead, but perhaps I am misreading.) I think there is an error near $(22)$ and $(23)$, and it seems like the meat of the argument is between page 7 and page 9, where the text claims "this FLT full proof is now completed". Even earlier, $(27)$ is establishing the inequality that implies FLT at the beginning of page 8.

I've done my best to narrow the focus of this question to a particular part of the text where I think the error is in order to limit the scope, but this is a text verification question, and the best kind of answer would explain why the author's approach *can't* work even after fixing trivial errors.

Comment: This is not anything related to the paper, just some unusual signs you do not expect to find in a paper. First, a paper that really proved FLT would not spend a page on its history. Second, a paper that really proved FLT would not have three historical references, and one math reference which it never even used in the paper. Third, why does the author do numerical examples if he proved it, that is unexpected. Of course, it could be just a very unusual author, but it has all the common unusual signs of a false proof.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Yes, my "crackpot alarm" triggered several times when I first looked at it. The main reason I revisited it anyway is because my friend has spent a lot of work writing out the argument (emails collected [here](http://us2.metamath.org:88/downloads/flt.pdf)) and I felt I had to give it serious consideration rather than just blowing it off for non-mathematical reasons (although I am still highly skeptical, of course).